# regex in go that match with no lowercase and at least one uppercase?

Tags: regex, go, regex-lookarounds

I need to find a regex in go that match when there is no lowercase and at least one uppercase.

For example:

```
"1 2 3 A"  : Match
"1 2 3"    : No match
"a A "     : no match
"AHKHGJHB" : Match
```

This work but in PHP not in Go (the `?=` token isn't working in Go):

```
(?=.*[A-Z].*)(?=^[^a-z]*$)
```

In my code this line call the regex:

```
isUppcase, _ := reg.MatchString(`^[^a-z]*$`, string)
```

Actually my regex catch when there is no lowercase but I want it also to catch when there is at least one uppercase.

Comment: See https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/ and use eg `\p{Lu}` and `Ll` (which comes closest to what you asked for).

Comment: I already have, but i think i just sucks on regex. Anyway the Wiktor Stribiżew's answer work for me .

Comment: Actually, I am very surprised at the number of downvotes for this question: the problem is clearly stated, there is a valid attempt with explanation what is wrong with it and there are sample strings with expected result.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
^\P{Ll}*\p{Lu}\P{Ll}*$
```

Or, a bit more efficient:

```
^\P{L}*\p{Lu}\P{Ll}*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JzZ07N/3).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `^\P{L}*` - 0 or more chars other than  letters
- `\p{Lu}` - an uppercase letter
- `\P{Ll}*` - 0 or more chars other than lowercase letters
- `$` - end of string.

[Go test](https://play.golang.org/p/DKSQeGnG_Yt):

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`^\P{L}*\p{Lu}\P{Ll}*$`)
    fmt.Println(re.MatchString(`1 2 3 A`))   
    fmt.Println(re.MatchString(`1 2 3`))   
    fmt.Println(re.MatchString(`a A`))   
    fmt.Println(re.MatchString(`AHKHGJHB`))   
    fmt.Println(re.MatchString(`Δ != Γ`)) 
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
false
true
true
```

Comment: I am sure Δ and Γ are upper case and ε and ρ are lowercase and neither work with your solution.

Comment: @Volker Ok, I added another test, `fmt.Println(re.MatchString(`Δ != Γ`))` returns true.